Include A3 PDF page in A4 LaTeX document
I want to include an A3 map in the appendix of my thesis. When I include the A3 PDF with the code below, it prints as an A4 page. How can I make it A3?
\begingroup 
\includepdf[landscape=true]{bedrock_map_whole_v3_A3.pdf}
\label{fig:geological_map_whole_app}
\endgroup


Are you wanting to (1) scale the A3 page down to A4 size, or (2) rotate and crop the A3 page so that you only get the A4 sized left or right half, or (3) have a different sized page in your pdf?

use the option fitpaper

I want an A3 page in the middle of the A4 pages. It will be a digital document, not printed.
